# Thevenin equivalent (verification of answer)

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, norton, verification

[image]

\$ R_{TH} = R1 + R2//R5 + R3//R4\$

Then considering the current source and the resistance R3 as a Norton circuit, one can convert it to Thevenin as follows \$V_I = -IR3\$. Then we have the voltage sources in series so

\$ V_{TH} = V1 + V2 -IR3\$

Does this make sense? If not how do I fix it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I agree with your answer, I guess 'I' is also a given value.

Comment: -1: I do not believe the answer is correct. More thorough math demonstration is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Redrawing originial circuit for clarity:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLETJz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Norton to Thevenin of I and R3 lead to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGM5MG.png)</sup>

Thevenin voltage is equal to open circuit voltage. Since there is no current through R1, its voltage drop is zero, leading to the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzWNTW.png)</sup>

Circuit equations:

$$
\frac{V_{th} - (V_x + V_1 - R_3I)}{R_3} + \frac{V_{th} - V_x}{R_4} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{(V_x + V_1 - R_3I) - V_{th}}{R_3} + \frac{V_x - V_2}{R_5} + \frac{V_x - V_{th}}{R_4} + \frac{V_x}{R_2} = 0
$$

Solution is:

$$
V_{th} = \frac{1}{(R_2+R_5)(R_3+R_4)}\times\\\{V_1(R_2R_4 + R_4R_5) + V_2(R_2R_3 + R_2R_4) - I(R_2R_3R_4 + R_3R_4R_5)\}
$$

Comment: R1 is open circuit? Do you know what a Norton equivalent is?

Comment: Yes, I do know what a Norton equivalent is. OP question is regarding to Thevenin voltage, which is equal to open circuit voltage (I believe you know that as well. Are you mistaking R3 for R1?).

Comment: No. Is two separate questions. You didn't calculate the Norton equivalent well, and R1 is not 'open'.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami Done editing. The Norton to Thevenin is positively correct, and R1 has no current, nor voltage drop.